# JMeter go back to previous sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, stress-testing, beanshell

I am quite new to jmeter, I am using it to load test an application. My current setup is good if running few threads at a time but gets problems when more users get connected.

Here's the scenario,

```
sample_1: request table data
sample_2: set table row with empty user column as used by current user
    |
    '-->post_process_beanshell: check if have error message
sample_3: do other stuff
```

Currently I am able to check if the 2nd sample has an error message, the question is how do I tell beanshell to go back to 1st sample when the 2nd sample has an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend put your "sample_3" under [If Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) like:

- Loop Controller (define maximum number of n-tries)

  - sample_1
  - sample_2

    - post_process_beanshell
  - If Controller: condition `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`

    - sample_3

**JMeterThread.last_sample_ok** - is a [pre-defined variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) which returns "true" if previous sampler was successful and "false" if not so if your "sample_2" will fail - "sample_3" won't be executed and the whole sequence will start over

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep going back to sampler1 until sampler2 beanshell returns true, use a [While controller.](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

Stick both sampler1 and sampler2 in a `while` controller which is conditional on the result of your error check.